# Javascript, stopping animation if mouse is on certain location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck with this problem and cant think of a way outside of this. Have a look at the image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xxjS.png

[image: reference image for the problem]

Now the problem is, the div is not a part of the li, and on leaving the li(and entering the div) the li collapses back. This needs to be handled and I am stuck on how to do this.

Below is the javascript code

```
    a.cache.brand_nav.find("li a").hover(function (c) {
        if (a.isTablet && c.currentTarget.href !== f) d.location = c.currentTarget.href;
        else {
            a.cache.brand_nav.find("li a").css('top', '0px'); //Collapsing all li's before expanding one
            c = b(this);
            c.stop(true, true).animate({ top: '-' + c.find("img").height() + 'px' }, 250, 'easeInCirc');
            $('#bgIdeas').stop(true, true).animate({ bottom: '+' + parseInt(parseInt(c.find("img").height())).toString() + 'px' }, 500, 'easeInCirc', false);
            $('.outerBGs').hide();
            $('#backgrounds').hide();
            if (this.className == 'ideas') {
                $('#ideasBG').stop(true, true).show(5000, 'easeOutExpo');
                $('#bgIdeas').empty();
                $('#bgIdeas').append('<p style=" position:absolute; left:22%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/ideas/ideas_worldofideas_thumb.jpg"><br>World of Ideas</p>         <p style=" position:absolute; left:32%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/ideas/ideas_history_thumb.jpg"><br>History</p>           <p style=" position:absolute; left:42%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/ideas/ideas_gulahmed_thumb.jpg"><br>About Gul Ahmed</p>          <p style=" position:absolute; left:52%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/ideas/ideas_partner_thumb.jpg"><br>Be an Ideas Partner</p>');
            }
            else
                if (this.className == 'women') {
                    $('#womenBG').stop(true, true).show(5000, 'easeOutExpo');
                    $('#bgIdeas').empty();
                    $('#bgIdeas').append('<p style=" position:absolute; left:42%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/women/women_fabrics_thumb.jpg"><br>Fabric</p>          <p style=" position:absolute; left:52%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/women/women_readytowear_thumb.jpg"><br>Ready to Wear</p>         <p style=" position:absolute; left:62%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/women/women_shoes_thumb.jpg"><br>Shoes</p>           <p style=" position:absolute; left:72%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/women/women_bags_thumb.jpg"><br>Bags</p>');
                }
                else
                    if (this.className == 'men') {
                        $('#menBG').stop(true, true).show(5000, 'easeOutExpo');
                        $('#bgIdeas').empty();
                        $('#bgIdeas').append('<p style=" position:absolute; left:20%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/men/men_fabrics_thumb.jpg"><br>Fabric</p>          <p style=" position:absolute; left:30%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/men/men_readytowear_thumb.jpg"><br>Ready to Wear</p>         <p style=" position:absolute; left:61%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/men/men_shoes_thumb.jpg"><br>Shoes</p>           <p style=" position:absolute; left:71%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/men/men_accesories_thumb.jpg"><br>Accessories</p>');
                    }
                    else
                        if (this.className == 'kids') {
                            $('#kidsBG').stop(true, true).show(5000, 'easeOutExpo');
                            $('#bgIdeas').empty();
                            $('#bgIdeas').append('<p style=" position:absolute; left:30%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/kids/kids_readytowear_thumb.jpg"><br>Ready to Wear</p>         <p style=" position:absolute; left:40%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/kids/kids_shoes_thumb.jpg"><br>Shoes</p>         <p style=" position:absolute; left:50%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/kids/kids_accessories_thumb.jpg"><br>Accessories</p>');
                        }
                        else
                            if (this.className == 'homes') {
                                $('#homesBG').stop(true, true).show(5000, 'easeOutExpo');
                                $('#bgIdeas').empty();
                                $('#bgIdeas').append('<p style=" position:absolute; left:30%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/home/bed_linen_thumb.jpg"><br>Bed Linen</p>            <p style=" position:absolute; left:40%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/home/bed_basics_thumb.jpg"><br>Bed Basics</p>            <p style=" position:absolute; left:50%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/home/kitchen_textile_thumb.jpg"><br>Kitchen Textile</p>          <p style=" position:absolute; left:60%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/home/bath_thumb.jpg"><br>Bath Accessories</p>            <p style=" position:absolute; left:70%; margin-top:10px;"><img src="images/home/home_accessories_thumb.jpg"><br>Home Accessories</p>');
                            }
    }
    },
            function () {
                c = b(this);
                    $('.outerBGs').stop(true, true).hide(5000, 'easeOutExpo');
                $('#backgrounds').stop(true, true).show(1000, 'easeOutExpo');
                $('#bgIdeas').stop(true, true).animate({ bottom: '0px' }, 250, 'easeInCirc');
                c.stop(true, true).animate({ top: '0px' }, 250, 'easeInCirc');
                //            $(document).unbind('mousemove');
                //            $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
                //                var offset = $('#bgIdeas').offset();
                //                result = offset.left <= e.pageX && offset.left + $('#bgIdeas').outerWidth() > e.pageX && offset.top <= e.pageY && offset.top + $('#bgIdeas').outerHeight() > e.pageY;
        //                //To see if mouse coordinates are under the area of div.
        //                //alert(parseInt(parseInt(offset.left) + parseInt($('#bgIdeas').outerWidth())) + '     ' + e.pageX + '         ' + parseInt(parseInt(offset.top) + parseInt($('#bgIdeas').outerHeight())) + '        ' + e.pageY);
        //                                        
        //                if (result == false) {
        //                    clearInterval(myRecFunc);
        //                    $('.bgs').show();
        //                    continueSlideShow();
        ////                    $('#bgIdeas').stop(true, true).animate({bottom: "0px"},500, "easeOutExpo", function () {$(document).unbind('mousemove');});
        ////                    c.stop(true, true).animate({top: "0px"},{ duration: 500, queue: false });

        //                    
        //                }
        //                else {
        //                }
        //            });
    });
```

The commented code above, is actually a method i tried before by mousemove event by catching the mouseposition and restricting the function from entering the code if the mouse is on the DIV, but it lead to improper functioning randomly, I guess that must have been because of binding and unbinding of event so fast. Please, I need help on this.

Comment: I can't see a div highlighted in red? Could you post the markup of the html?

Comment: I am really sorry, must have forgotten to highlight it, it is the one in grey in which there are a couple of thumbnails. It rises and collapses with the li.

Comment: So to confirm, you want the functionality to be as follows. A user  hovers over a navigation option, the navigation pops up. When the user hovers off the navigation but is still within the <div> above the navigation bar, it stays popped up, otherwise it collapses?

Comment: I'm guessing you can't post a link to the site. If not, it would be really helpful if you could create a jsfiddle of jsbin of the isolated code (css, javascript & html).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using two classes that each have `display:block`.

Whenever the li has at least one of those classes, it will show. So the li itself and the div each remove one displayed class on `mouseover` and remove it's own (respective) class on `mouseout`.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/xmeQT/)

Comment: the problem is, that li is always there(displayed) but the position is determined by javascript (I have applied .animate(top:-(size of image)))

Comment: You could insert an if in to your function to see if these classes were present. I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: Now, mouseenter and leave or hover wont call because the position is set to absolute, and can only be set to absolute and fixed

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better, completely different answer

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/qdbE5/)

Put a delegated listener on the lowest shared parent of the `div` and the `li`. In the example, this is the `body`. That listener then checks to see if the event was on one of these two elements and, if not, performs an action on the `li`.

Edited to include child elements.